# NextJS rewrite with trailingSlash for only certan paths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

As per the documentation for NextJS, it by default rewrites any URL that ends with a slash `/` to without the slash.

Ex: `localhost:3000/register/` to `localhost:3000/register`.

This behavior is fine for the app itself, but the external API I am using requires the trailing slash.

I can set it to rewrite to a trailing slash, but that does it for all endpoints, both web and api endpoints.

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
}
```

Is there any way to make it so that it only rewrites to a trailing slash for certain paths?  Ex: rewrite any path that starts with `/api` to have a trailing slash, while leaving the rest of the app alone?

Comment: are you using nextjs with custom server?

Comment: @DarrylRN currently it's just `yarn dev` for dev, and Django's `runserver` command for the API.  I have module rewrites in my next.config.js to handle the rewrites.